# How can I access the video editor?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, video

I just downloaded the software and don't know how to get to the video editor. All I see is a 3D maker or something.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! You are probably referring to the 3D view  and the Video Sequence (or  maybe the Movie Clip..) editors. Here's a link to the [manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/index.html) to help you with terminology.

Comment: Also take a look at this resource page: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the preset layouts.

On the top menu change from default to video editing:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can switch any view into any another via the icon in the left in each ones *Header bar*. This is where usually the menu is located.
You can switch to predefined layouts in the Info view where it says "Default" at the top of Blender next to the file menu.
[image: Info Header Bar]
Note, that the corresponding Header bar of a view might sometimes appear at its bottom... But it gets somewhat highlighted together with the view when you hover your mouse over a view. Per default Blender will open a layout with a *3D View(port)* for you.
[image: 3D View]

It's easiest to switch to the "Video Editing" layout which is the last entry in this drop down list in the *Info* header bar at the top. You can cycle through this list via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd>. This will open a layout with the *Video Sequence Editor* where you can place, edit and preview your strips of your footage. That is what you'd most likely want to see.

There's a brilliant [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjTn8GsRk48&index=2&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) by Mikeycal Meyers on this topic which explains Blenders layout short and detailled enough to get you started.

Another possibility is to use the *Motion Tracking* view for more advanced stuff when you want to undistort a Movie Clip, track some markers to correct rotation or smooth some camera movements or create a Mask for it. You can even use it for a [complete camera solve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v-Bf9XOXIg&list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g) to integrate 3D elements into your footage as Sebastian König does explain pretty well. But to render out a Movie Clip, you'd have to add it into a VSE or insert it in a *Node Tree* view in composition mode.

Answer (score 1):

The video editor is called the video sequence editor right above the UV/ Image editor. Make sure to download blender from [blender.org](http://blender.org) as it is the safest to  download.

Comment: It's right *below* the "UV Editing" layout... And above the **Editor Type** *UV/Image Editor*.